# Typo in Chandlers statistical mechanics p.60?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I'm quite certain this is a typo when cross checking the same information. On page 60 in Chandler's "Introduction to modern statistical mechanics", He states the following in reference to the micro-canonical ensemble

> According to the statistical assumption, the probability of a macroscopic state v for an equilibrium system is $$P_v=1/\Omega(N,V,E)$$
> for all states in the ensemble. For states outside the ensemble, for example those for which $E_v\neq E$ $P_v$ is zero.

My issue here is, clearly, he ought to mean the probability for a microscopic state, as he mentiones all microscopic states are equally likely, so the probability of a specific one is simply 1/(number of total micro-states). When I cross check with other sources, my reasoning seems sound, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes you are right, it should be read as: the probability of observing a microscopic $v$ state **consistent** with the macroscopic quantities E,N, V is... Or conversely, there are $ \Omega(N,V,E) $ microscopic states that lead to a macroscopic energy $E$, a volume $V$ with $N$ particles.